# Azure Cognitive services - TTS

Tags: azure, api, postman, azure-cognitive-services

I got an api keys for Azure Cognitive services, but I can't find any documentation how I am calling this service through postmen. Anybody has experience with this?

Comment: You can have a look here for [Text to speech example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstart-dotnet-text-to-speech) let me know if you have any more help regarding implementation.

Comment: Let me know if you have any more concern. Thanks

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I don't need .net core project, just an api call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you are trying to call `Text To Speech` service with your keys. There are two steps for that.

**1. Need Access Token**

You have to get your token like this format:

```
Request URL: https://YourResourceEndpoint/sts/v1.0/issuetoken
Method: POST
Hearder: Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:YourKeys
```

See The Screen shot for clarity:

[image]

***Code Snippet:***

```cs
public async Task<string> GetSpeechServiceToken()
        {
            try
            {
                string tokenUrl = $"https://YourServiceURL.cognitiveservices.azure.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken";
                var tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl);
                tokenRequest.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "subscriptionKey");
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var tokenResponse = await client.SendAsync(tokenRequest);

                    var token = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    return token;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                ex.Message.ToString();
            }
            return null;

        }
```

You could have a look on [official Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-text-to-speech#how-to-use-an-access-token)

**2. Get List Of Voices With Token You Have Received Earlier**

You can request for `Text To Speech` voice list Like below:

```
Request URL: https://centralus.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/voices/list
Method : GET
Authorization: Bearer Token Paste Your Token Here
```

See the screen shot for clarity

[image]

You could find more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-text-to-speech#get-a-list-of-voices)

**Note:** In case of your test account You can create [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services/)

[image]

**Update:**

**I would sent a request and somehow I got an uri or something where I can hear it? is this possible?**

Yeah its possible. But in that case you have to use sdk. Here Is the [complete sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Convert-Text-to-Speech-in-40f1382b#content).

Comment: Thanks, I already have a token. But I wanted somehow to test audio sample. for example I sent a request and somehow I got an uri or something where I can hear it? is this possible? I am assuming that I am getting array of bytes right (as a audio file)?

Comment: @Stefan0309 I have updated my answer with your sample project. You can try it out. Let me know if you have any more query.

Comment: Why where is the play section says Invalid source ? I put my key into the program

Comment: I successfully  obtained token, but still, invalid source is displayed.

Comment: I guess you should check your request endpoint. See my reference for clarity.

Comment: No, it's working for english and all languages whch was in the example, but for example Croatian hr-HR language not working. I've read documentation, and for Croatian language there is a Male voice, so I put 'Male' in the code instead of 'Female' but still the same, I have an exception.

Comment: Can you Write here your exception please.

Comment: ```{System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
   at System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute..ctor(XName name, Object value)
   at TextToSpeechApp.BusinessLayer.TextToSpeechService.GenerateSsml(String lang, String gender, String name, String text) in C:\BVC\TTS\C#\TextToSpeechApp\BusinessLayer\TextToSpeechService.cs:line 78
   at TextToSpeechApp.BusinessLayer.TextToSpeechService.<TranslateText>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\BVC\TTS\C#\TextToSpeechApp\BusinessLayer\TextToSpeechService.cs:line 28
```

Comment: It breaks on `Translate` method when I call the service, and wait for the response.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. It would be good for me if you post a new question with your code sample as this error is not related to this question. So I can easily reproduce it with your code sample. Thanks. Waiting for your question...

Comment: I posted another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158760/azure-cognitive-services-tts-an-error-for-other-language-in-sample-app