# Azure Cognitive Services TTS - an error for other language in sample app

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, text-to-speech

I wanted to implement an api call for Azure Cognitive Services TTS.
And by courtesy of @Md Farid Uddin Kiron stackoverflow user and the question that we discussed on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56920878/azure-cognitive-services-tts) 
So, I pulled down an sample code that is an .netcore web app which communicates with Azure. [Sample link is here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Convert-Text-to-Speech-in-40f1382b#content)

I have a following problem:
The app works perfectly with predefined languages in a model such as:

```
    public List<SelectListItem> LanguagePreference { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
       new SelectListItem { Value = "NA", Text = "-Select-" },
       new SelectListItem { Value = "en-US", Text = "English (United States)"  },
       new SelectListItem { Value = "en-IN", Text = "English (India)"  },
       new SelectListItem { Value = "ta-IN", Text = "Tamil (India)"  },
       new SelectListItem { Value = "hi-IN", Text = "Hindi (India)"  },
       new SelectListItem { Value = "te-IN", Text = "Telugu (India)"  }
    };
```

but when I add for example an italian language (it-IT, hr-HR - those are language codes for fields Value), the code breaks in HomeController on method Translate.

Comment: I am not sure whether it support the language you are trying.

Comment: it says that supports over 45 languages among them Croatian and Italian https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/language-support

Comment: Wait working on it...little busy with something

Comment: Please check my findings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduce your problem successfully.

As per my findings there are some key points to language supports like:

1. [Subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/regions#standard-and-neural-voices) Free subscription doesn't allow all language
2. [Region of Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/regions#standard-and-neural-voices)
3. `var requestBody = this.GenerateSsml(lang, "Female",
   this.ServiceName(lang), content);`

***Note:*** language that doesn't support Female also can be the issue.

***Your Case:***

In your code you could try with below code at `LanguagePreference` list

```cs
 new SelectListItem { Value = "es-ES", Text = "es-ES,(Spanish)"  }
```

Also Change on below code under `ServiceName` I have tested with Spanish which works fine.

```cs
 values.Add("es-ES", "Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (es-ES, Laura, Apollo)");
```

***Point To Remember:***

Our code base is alright. problem is not related to code. Please be sure your subscriptions and region support translation you are trying.  can also rise your support ticket on azure portal.

Comment: If I could find any more issue , will keep you updated.

Comment: thanks! I successfully managed to get working with Croatian language, the problem was that I didnt put in ServiceName Croatian..

Comment: No worries, I am also deeply analyzing it , will update you soon.