# In Azure Cognitive Services Text Translation what is the endpoint `https://<resource name>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken` for?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, machine-translation

Want to try out the Text Translation API from , I created my text translation resource, as described at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/business/trial/#get-started, and was presented with a subscription key and an endpoint `https://<resource name>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken`.

I proceeded to replicate the sample code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/quickstart-translate?pivots=programming-language-csharp (also on Github).

That code wants the subscription key and endpoint added as environment variables, and I did so, using the strings provided to me when creating the resource. However, trying to run the sample code it fails with a 404 when going to the endpoint. Looking more carefully at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/quickstart-translate?pivots=programming-language-csharp, I noticed that it told me to use `https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/` as endpoint, not the URL above. After that change, the code worked.

So what is the `https://<resource name>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken` endpoint for? Certainly one gets the impression it's the endpoint to use for translation requests, so maybe clarify the documentation there?

Comment: Did you mean Endpoint for getting token ?

Comment: I am guessing that is what it is, but nothing says so. It would be helpful if you were told that when you create your text translation resource.

Comment: You could check a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56920878/azure-cognitive-services-tts/56923740#56923740) let me know if it make sense. If the link doesn't help you I will show you full step on answer.