# 404Resource Not Found postman post request for speech to text REST API

Tags: azure, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I tried to use **REST API azure cognitive services** for speech to text transcription. The resource is created on azure portal with key and endpoint (https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken)

When I try to create POST request from postman for some audio file form file system I got the error

**404Resource Not Found **

Using **Postman** I defined URL https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken/v1?language=de-DE&format=detailed

and created the parameters for language and format

In **Headers**I added values for 
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:....
Accept:application/json;text/xml
Content-Type: audio/wav;codecs=audio/pcm;samplerate=16000

And in **Body** I selected **binary** option and find audio file in folder but after that got error 404?
Is there any missing step in preparing the request for an audio file?

Here are screenshots of steps what I did:
1. [image]

2. [image]

3.[image]

Comment: Please refer to [this docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56920878/azure-cognitive-services-tts/56923740#56923740) hope that might help. Let me know if you have any more concern

Comment: It looks like you are mixing 2 different steps: the one to get a token and the one to process your speech-to-text operation. Can you add more details on what you are calling / how: add full url and payloads (just replace secrets by ****) so that we might help

Comment: I added screenshots of steps on how I tried to create a request for a speech to text.  I tried to follow steps from pluralsights course for speech cognitive services. Please let me know is there any manual which I can use for using REST API a for batch processing.

Comment: Nicolas, please could you check my comments and send me what could I further do with REST API for speech to text.